# add buy/sell trend meter script

Tags: pine-script

I would add BUY/SELL shapes up/below candle, when:
buy: all conditions are green and price is under EMA200
sell: all conditions are red and price is below EMA200

is it possible?
I tried to add without result:

```
`plotshape(MSBar1PositiveWaveTrendSignal  and TrendBars3Positive : na,title="Up", color=color.new(#00ff00,1), location=location.belowbar, style=shape.triangleup, size=size.normal)
plotshape(MSBar1NegativeWaveTrendSignal  and TrendBars3Negative: na,title="Down", color=color.new(#ff0000, 1), location=location.abovebar, style=shape.triangledown, size=size.normal)`
```

Furthermore Pinescript geves me error:
**line 12: Could not find function or function reference 'study'**

https://www.tradingview.com/script/Ciurp4Qn-Trend-Meter/

Comment: Please format your code so we can read it.

Comment: yes.u're right. done, thanks